# Replace XML element with multiple copies of that element

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file with elements like

```
  <function name="negate" arg1="multivector"/>
```

I want to transform these elements so that `multivector` is replaced by each of 8 things, including `vector`, `bivector`, `rotor`, etc.  So the transformed XML will have 8 `negate` elements:

```
  <function name="negate" arg1="multivector"/>
  <function name="negate" arg1="multivector3"/>
  <function name="negate" arg1="vector"/>
  <function name="negate" arg1="vector3"/>
  <function name="negate" arg1="vector"/>
  <function name="negate" arg1="bivector3"/>
  <function name="negate" arg1="rotor"/>
  <function name="negate" arg1="rotor3"/>
```

Similarly, I have elements with two types of `arg`:

```
  <function name="add" arg1="multivector" arg2="multivector"/>
```

The transformed XML should have 64 `add` elements with args being the various combinations of `vector`, etc., though I'll spare us all the pain of writing those out explicitly.

I can figure out how to transform `multivector` to any 1 of my new things, but I can't quite figure out how to make it copy the same thing multiple times.  Do I have to do the ugly replacement manually?  Can I elegantly loop over all 8 or 64 things automatically?

---

## My basic first effort

The following is what I've got so far, but it just does the most basic thing of replacing every `arg2="multivector"` attribute with `arg2="vector"`.  General style improvements are also welcome, as I'm new to XML.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <!-- Find any arg2="multivector" attribute and replace -->
  <xsl:template match="function[@arg2='multivector']/@arg2">
    <xsl:attribute name="arg2">vector</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Just copy anything that didn't match above -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: I hope you didn't mean to create @arg2 multiple times with different values. That wouldn't be possible as an element can have attributes with unique names only.

Comment: I didn't mean multiple `arg2` attributes in the same element; I meant multiple elements, with various combinations of the `arg1` and `arg2` attributes.  I've edited the question to clarify.  Thanks!

Comment: What about inverting it? Placing your data in a XML like: 
`<vectors><vector>vector</vector>...<vector>rotor</vector></vectors>`
And generating the rest in your stylesheet? Could it be that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the other answers quite worked for me.  But I did figure out how to basically just do a for-loop using Thomas's answer.  I ended up using a few templates more-or-less like the following.  By adjusting the priority of the templates and matching different things, I managed to get the results I needed.  [For some reason, I also needed to add newlines `&#10;` after most of the functions.

```
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:variable name="smvTypes"
                select="'mv', 'mv3', 'vector',
                        'vector3', 'bivector', 'bivector3',
                        'pseudovector', 'spinor', 'spinor3'"/>

  <xsl:template match="function[@arg1='anysmv']" priority="2">
    <xsl:variable name="functionElement" select="."/>
    <xsl:for-each select="1 to count($smvTypes)">
      <function>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$functionElement/@*"/> <!-- Copy all attributes -->
        <xsl:attribute name="arg1"> <!-- Reset my attribute -->
          <xsl:value-of select="subsequence($smvTypes, ., 1)"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </function>
      <xsl:if test=". &lt; count($smvTypes)">
        <xsl:text>&#10;  </xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have some input data like this:

```
<functions>
    <function name="xxxxx" arg1="yyyyy" />
    <function name="negate" arg1="multivector"/>
    <function name="negate" arg1="zzzzz" />
    <function name="add" arg1="multivector" arg2="multivector"/>
    <function name="add" arg1="aaaaa" arg2="bbbbb" />
    <function name="add" arg1="ccccc" arg2="ddddd" />
</functions>
```

And you want to generate a new XML preserving all the existing elements except the ones that have the format:

```
<function name="negate" arg1="multivector"/>
```

and

```
<function name="add" arg1="multivector" arg2="multivector"/>
```

That you wish to replace them by *n* `<function name="negate" arg1="..."/>` elements and `n*n` `<function name="add" arg1="..." arg2="..."/>`, while keeping elements like `<function name="xxxxx" arg1="yyyyy" />` and `<function name="negate" arg1="zzzzz" />` where they are.

You could place the data you are going to use for the args in a separate file (you could also have it in the XSL file, defining a local namespace for it). I will use one with three elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<vectors>
    <vector>vector</vector>
    <vector>bivector</vector>
    <vector>rotor</vector>
</vectors>
```

I'll call this file `vectors.xml`.

Then you read that file into a XSLT stylesheet, store the `vector` node-set in a variable,  loop through each element twice and generate all the combinations. You also store the input document functions in a variable, so you can copy the nodes that aren't affected.

This is the stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:variable name="vectors" select="document('vectors.xml')/vectors"/>
    <xsl:variable name="functions" select="/functions"/>

    <xsl:template match="functions">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$vectors/vector"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="vector">
        <xsl:variable name="arg1" select="."/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$functions/function">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@name='negate' and @arg1='multivector'">
                    <function name="negate" arg1="{$arg1}"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="@name='add' and @arg1='multivector' and @arg2='multivector'">
                    <xsl:for-each select="$vectors/vector">
                        <function name="add" arg1="{$arg1}" arg2="{.}"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using the `functions` file containing the data listed above as input, and having the `vectors.xml` file also listed above in the same directory, it will generate:

```
<functions>
   <function name="something" arg1="something"/>
   <function name="negate" arg1="vector"/>
   <function name="negate" arg1="kkk"/>
   <function name="add" arg1="vector" arg2="vector"/>
   <function name="add" arg1="vector" arg2="bivector"/>
   <function name="add" arg1="vector" arg2="rotor"/>
   <function name="add" arg1="abc" arg2="xyz"/>
   <function name="add" arg1="xyz" arg2="xyz"/>
   <function name="something" arg1="something"/>
   <function name="negate" arg1="bivector"/>
   <function name="negate" arg1="kkk"/>
   <function name="add" arg1="bivector" arg2="vector"/>
   <function name="add" arg1="bivector" arg2="bivector"/>
   <function name="add" arg1="bivector" arg2="rotor"/>
   <function name="add" arg1="abc" arg2="xyz"/>
   <function name="add" arg1="xyz" arg2="xyz"/>
   <function name="something" arg1="something"/>
   <function name="negate" arg1="rotor"/>
   <function name="negate" arg1="kkk"/>
   <function name="add" arg1="rotor" arg2="vector"/>
   <function name="add" arg1="rotor" arg2="bivector"/>
   <function name="add" arg1="rotor" arg2="rotor"/>
   <function name="add" arg1="abc" arg2="xyz"/>
   <function name="add" arg1="xyz" arg2="xyz"/>
</functions>
```

Comment: This is a nice idea, but I actually have many more functions than just `add` and `negate`.  So it'd kind of just be reversing the problem without solving it.

Comment: In that case you can load the file using `document()` and process its nodes as well, merging the files.

Comment: You want to place the result in the same place where the original element was before?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem!

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <!-- The terminating space in this list is required for being able
       to use the "chopping off" method substring-before(..., ' ') 
       for all values, including the last one. -->
  <xsl:variable name="argValues" 
    select="'multivector multivector3 vector vector3 vector bivector3 rotor rotor3 '"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="function[@arg1='multivector']" priority="1">
    <!-- We solve the problem recursively: 
         This template applies itself multiple times.

         We start with a complete space separated list of argValues 
         and chop off the first value in arg1Values in each iteration.
         We only chop off the first value in arg2Values if we have 
         used up all values in arg1Values.
         In this case, we also "re-fill" the arg1Values list.

         Initially, the apply-templates in the identity template sends us here. 
         It does not supply any parameters, so we "initialize" them with the
         complete list of argValues here. -->
    <xsl:param name="arg1Values" select="$argValues"/>
    <xsl:param name="arg2Values" select="$argValues"/>

    <!-- Here, the "chopping off" takes place. -->
    <xsl:variable name="currentArg1Value" select="substring-before($arg1Values,' ')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="remainingArg1Values" select="substring-after($arg1Values,' ')"/>
    <!-- We also chop off the first value from arg2Values,
         but we only supply the chopped off list to the recursion
         if all values from arg1Values have been used up. 
         Otherwise, we continue using the current state of arg2Values. -->
    <xsl:variable name="currentArg2Value" select="substring-before($arg2Values,' ')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="remainingArg2Values" select="substring-after($arg2Values,' ')"/>

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$currentArg1Value != ''">
        <!-- If there still are arg1 values in the list,
             we create a function element with  -->
        <function name="{@name}" arg1="{$currentArg1Value}">
          <!-- We only have to add an @arg2 attribute if the
               matched function element already has one. -->
          <xsl:if test="@arg2">
            <xsl:attribute name="arg2">
              <xsl:value-of select="$currentArg2Value"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
          </xsl:if>
        </function>
        <!-- We re-apply the template with the first value
             chopped off from the list of arg1 values. -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
          <xsl:with-param name="arg1Values" select="$remainingArg1Values"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="arg2Values" select="$arg2Values"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:when>

      <xsl:when test="@arg2 and $remainingArg2Values != ''">
        <!-- If there are no more arg1 values in the list, 
             we go on with the next arg2 value.
             We're not supplying arg1Values so that the default 
             (the full list) takes effect. -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
          <xsl:with-param name="arg2Values" select="$remainingArg2Values"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:when>

      <!-- If we no <when> case applies, all lists have been used up
           and we've output all needed argument combinations.
           The recursion terminates. -->
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="argValues" select="(
      'multivector','multivector3','vector','vector3','vector','bivector3','rotor','rotor3'
     )" as="xs:string*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="function[@arg1='multivector']" priority="1">
    <!-- We do two nested iterations over the list of argValues.
         During those iterations, we'll lose the matched function element
         as our "current node", therefore we save it to a variable. -->
    <xsl:variable name="functionElement" select="." as="element()"/>

    <!-- If we the matched function alement has an @arg2 attribute,
         we iterate over the full list of argument values.
         If we don't have @arg2, we use the dummy string 'noArg2'
         so that we have something to "iterate over". -->
    <xsl:for-each select="if (@arg2) then $argValues else 'noArg2'">
      <!-- Like the functionElement, we save the arg2 value to a variable
           so that we can enter the next for-each. -->
      <xsl:variable name="arg2" select="." as="xs:string"/>

      <xsl:for-each select="$argValues">
        <function name="{$functionElement/@name}" arg1="{.}">
          <!-- We only need to add @arg2 if the matched
               function element already has one. -->
          <xsl:if test="$functionElement/@arg2">
            <xsl:attribute name="arg2">
              <xsl:value-of select="$arg2"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
          </xsl:if>
        </function>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Input**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
  <function name="negate" arg1="multivector"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="multivector" arg2="multivector"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="otherArg" arg2="multivector"/>
  <function name="noArgs"/>  
</test>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
  <function name="negate" arg1="multivector"/>
  <function name="negate" arg1="multivector3"/>
  <function name="negate" arg1="vector"/>
  <function name="negate" arg1="vector3"/>
  <function name="negate" arg1="vector"/>
  <function name="negate" arg1="bivector3"/>
  <function name="negate" arg1="rotor"/>
  <function name="negate" arg1="rotor3"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="multivector" arg2="multivector"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="multivector3" arg2="multivector"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="vector" arg2="multivector"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="vector3" arg2="multivector"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="vector" arg2="multivector"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="bivector3" arg2="multivector"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="rotor" arg2="multivector"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="rotor3" arg2="multivector"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="multivector" arg2="multivector3"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="multivector3" arg2="multivector3"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="vector" arg2="multivector3"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="vector3" arg2="multivector3"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="vector" arg2="multivector3"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="bivector3" arg2="multivector3"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="rotor" arg2="multivector3"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="rotor3" arg2="multivector3"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="multivector" arg2="vector"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="multivector3" arg2="vector"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="vector" arg2="vector"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="vector3" arg2="vector"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="vector" arg2="vector"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="bivector3" arg2="vector"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="rotor" arg2="vector"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="rotor3" arg2="vector"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="multivector" arg2="vector3"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="multivector3" arg2="vector3"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="vector" arg2="vector3"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="vector3" arg2="vector3"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="vector" arg2="vector3"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="bivector3" arg2="vector3"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="rotor" arg2="vector3"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="rotor3" arg2="vector3"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="multivector" arg2="vector"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="multivector3" arg2="vector"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="vector" arg2="vector"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="vector3" arg2="vector"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="vector" arg2="vector"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="bivector3" arg2="vector"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="rotor" arg2="vector"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="rotor3" arg2="vector"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="multivector" arg2="bivector3"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="multivector3" arg2="bivector3"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="vector" arg2="bivector3"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="vector3" arg2="bivector3"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="vector" arg2="bivector3"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="bivector3" arg2="bivector3"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="rotor" arg2="bivector3"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="rotor3" arg2="bivector3"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="multivector" arg2="rotor"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="multivector3" arg2="rotor"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="vector" arg2="rotor"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="vector3" arg2="rotor"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="vector" arg2="rotor"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="bivector3" arg2="rotor"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="rotor" arg2="rotor"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="rotor3" arg2="rotor"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="multivector" arg2="rotor3"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="multivector3" arg2="rotor3"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="vector" arg2="rotor3"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="vector3" arg2="rotor3"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="vector" arg2="rotor3"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="bivector3" arg2="rotor3"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="rotor" arg2="rotor3"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="rotor3" arg2="rotor3"/>
  <function name="add" arg1="otherArg" arg2="multivector"/>
  <function name="noArgs"/>  
</test>
```

Comment: I can use `saxon` (though `xsltproc` is presumably more widely installed?), so the more elegant 2.0 approach would be welcome too!

Comment: This almost what I need.  I probably should have mentioned that there are some `add` functions that have something other than `multivector` for `arg1` and/or `arg2`, and I don't want to do the replacements on anything other than `multivector`.  I'm still trying to understand how your answer works so I could change it appropriately, but any help would be much appreciated.  :)

Comment: You probably want to only match `function[@arg1='multivector']`. I added lots of comments and an XSLT 2.0 variant. If anything remains unclear, feel free to ask!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works in XSLT 2.0, that may even scale up to support an **arg3** too if you were crazy enough to try...

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:variable name="vectors" select="document('vectors.xml')/vectors"/>

   <xsl:template match="function[@arg1='multivector']">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$vectors/vector">
         <xsl:with-param name="function" select="."/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="vectors"/>

   <xsl:template match="vector">
      <xsl:param name="function"/>
      <xsl:param name="arg" select="1"/>
      <xsl:param name="attrs"/>
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="$function/@*[name()=concat('arg', (number($arg) + 1))]">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$vectors/vector">
               <xsl:with-param name="function" select="$function"/>
               <xsl:with-param name="arg" select="number($arg) + 1"/>
               <xsl:with-param name="attrs">
                  <xsl:copy-of select="$attrs"/>
                  <attribute name="arg{$arg}">
                     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                  </attribute>
               </xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <function name="{$function/@name}">
               <xsl:for-each select="$attrs/attribute">
                  <xsl:attribute name="{@name}">
                     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                  </xsl:attribute>
               </xsl:for-each>
               <xsl:attribute name="arg{$arg}">
                  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
               </xsl:attribute>
            </function>
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This assumes you have a separate file, called **vectors.xml** that contained the following XML

```
<vectors>
    <vector>vector</vector>
    <vector>multivector</vector>
    <vector>multivector3</vector>
    <vector>vector</vector>
    <vector>vector3</vector>
    <vector>vector</vector>
    <vector>bivector3</vector>
    <vector>rotor</vector>
    <vector>rotor3</vector>
</vectors>
```